# Write to facebook friend's wall from java

Tags: java, rest, facebook-graph-api

using a person's access token, I am able to obtain the person's friend's facebookId. Will someone please provide me an example of posting a message to a friend's wall from java? I am using the api: com.restfb.

More specifically, I need to include an attachment as part of my message; the attachment being extra messages.

Comment: Well, "… use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the feed connection of the User object".

Answer (score 1):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed, part of which says:

> You can create a link, post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the PROFILE_ID/feed connection

So try creating a post, with something like:

```
String uid = "...";
DefaultFacebookClient client = ...;
FacebookType postId = client.publish(
    uid + "/feed", FacebookType.class, 
    Parameter.with("message", "Hello, world"), 
    Parameter.with("link", "http://www.google.com"));
```

According to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts) you can only attach one of the posting user's Facebook photos.